# Using iis 10, how am i enabling CORS for all requests? WebAPI2

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-web-api2, iis-10

For the past 2 hours I'm trying to enable CORS in my project.

Things i tried and did not work:

1. **Enabling CORS through code:**

```cs
In WebApiConfig.cs

config.EnableCors();
```

```cs
In MyController.cs

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

2. **Enabling CORS trough IIS CORS module:**

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

downloaded and installed. After that i tried to follow the instructions in the references yet no positive result.

How do I enable it?!

**If it matters, for my client I'm using React+axios.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm stupid, the solution was simple:

Add those two lines to your webApiConfig.cs :

```
        var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

**Important**:
DO NOT combine two solutions because it will cause a "Too much cors" problem.